# JQGrid onSelectRow event and jquery.simplemodal.js modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jqgrid, simplemodal

I am trying to show a modal window using jquery.simplemodal.js JQuery plugin everytime I click on a row of a JQGrid.

After doing it, once the user click "Yes" on the modal window I show a document on an Iframe using the info retrieved from my row, if they click "No" then the Iframe shows a form to edit some info related to this document. The idea is to keep the Iframe content blank until the user clicks on one of the buttons. To accomplish this I am using JQGrid  onSelectRow event as follows:

```
onSelectRow: function () {

            var id = $("#tabResBusUbi").getGridParam('selrow');
            var row = $('#tabResBusUbi').jqGrid('getRowData', id);
            viewDocument = false;

            myconfirm('Open the document view?', function () {
                viewDocument = true;            
            });

             if (viewDocument) {

                $('#ifrShowPdf').ready(function () {
                    $('#divLoading').css('display', 'none');
                });

                $('#ifrShowPdf').attr('src', 'resource\\' + row.filepath);
                $('#ifrShowPdf').css('display', 'block');

            } else {
                var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
                $('#ifrShowPdf').attr('src', 'document.asp?r=' + rnd + '&o=d&a=a&p=' + id);
                $('#ifrShowPdf').css('display', 'block');
            }

            return false;

}

function myconfirm(message, callback) {

$('#confirm').modal({

    closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
    position: ["20%", ],
    overlayId: 'confirm-overlay',
    containerId: 'confirm-container',
    onShow: function (dialog) {

        var modal = this;
        $('.message', dialog.data[0]).append(message);

        $('.yes', dialog.data[0]).click(function () {                
            if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                callback.apply();
                $('#confirm-overlay').css('z-index', 5000);
            }                
            modal.close(); 
        });
    }
});

}
```

After I click on the row, the modal popups, but also the Iframe shows the edit document form even when I haven't clicked on any of the option buttons. If I click the "Yes" option after, the document is viewed but, this is not what I intend to do.

I would appreciate any suggestions to make this work.

Comment: I don't know `jquery.simplemodal.js`, but it seems that you should to move `if (viewDocument) {...} else {...}` part of your code inside of body of `function` of `myconfirm('Open the document view?', function () {/*move it here*/});`. Moreover `id` is the first parameter of `onSelectRow` callback. You don't need use `$("#tabResBusUbi").getGridParam('selrow')`. By the way it's better to use `$(this)` instead of `$("#tabResBusUbi")`.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I have tried that before setting the viewDocument flag to true inside the callback, however the code outside it that checks the flag viewDocument value set inside gets executed first, so always does the "false" part of the code even when I set "return false" to prevent it inside the callback. 
I think it has to do with the onSelectRow event bubbling up/expanding since I don't how to use e.preventDefault() in this case like is done with a link.